# kids who commit suicide

Tags: fiqh, children, suicide

A boy in my neighbors commited suicide yesterday due to continuous torture by his teacher. He was just 16 and was an innocent kid. What does Islam say about kids who suicide?

Comment: 16 is not a kid.

Comment: precisely you are right. 16 years old is an adult who is at the age of puberty and doing Islamic ... is Wajib . . .

Answer (score 1):

Suicide in Islam is never acceptable (even during times of war). There are several conditions that have to be met for Allah to punish those who commit such act:

- Person must have reached puberty
- Person is sound of mind
- Person knows that doing such thing is forbidden and the ruling associated with it.

If the person meets such conditions, you can check out the following Hadiths to see what the punishment can be:

> Prophet (blessings and peace of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever throws himself down from a mountain and kills himself will be throwing himself down in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever. Whoever drinks poison and kills himself will be sipping it in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever. Whoever kills himself with a piece of iron will have that iron in his hand, thrusting it into his belly in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5442) and Muslim (109)

And

> Narrated from Thaabit ibn Dahhaak (may Allaah be pleased with him) that the Messenger of Allaah (blessings and peace of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever kills himself with something will be punished with it on the Day of Resurrection.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5700) and Muslim (110).

Answer (score 0):

Suicide is one of deadly or major sins as Mr.Makarem Shirazi says in the link bellow:(Its in persian)

http://portal.anhar.ir/node/2951#gsc.tab=0

He says that suicide is not accepted, like firing your own estates just because of this reason that you are destroying your own life.

in the answer of the question that "will they be forgiven by god or not?" he says: maybe god bless them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The asker is asking about children specifically who commit suicide, as children who didn't reach puberty are not accounted for sins.

Comment: @Abdel Rahman, you are right to some extent. Of course the answer looks as nice brief answer too. / On the other hand, I reckon, the point or problem which made you don't consider the answer as a related answer = it is related to the questioner who deemed a 16 years old person as a kid. But I assume you agree that a 16 years old boy or girl is at the age of puberty. / Although it can be investigated separatedly as a suicide of the kid (below the age of puberty too) (as you remarked) / Thanks for your attention. / likewise thanks for dear Mahyar's answer.

Comment: Yes, that's true @Ali__________علي